# Run Sql Job in The first day of every shamsi month (persian date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-job

I want to run a SQL Server Agent job every first day of shamsi (persian) month.

Comment: Build your own calendar table, scheduled your job to execute daily, checks for firs day of the month based on your calendar and to decide to execute the job or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must schedule the job as Daily and first of your query check that if today is the first day of shamsi month then continue else exit.